# text-transform: capitalize issue in IE

Tags: capitalization, css

I am having problem with css property of `text:transform`. When I set it to capitalize, it behaves differently in IE7 and IE8. The Product title of page[1] shows `apple tree 'Gala'` in other browsers while in IE it shows `apple tree 'gala'` . Note the 'g' letter after quote. I want the 'g' to be capital in both IE and other browsers.

Is there any hack or extra setting I need do, to get it working in IE ?

[1] - http://shop.shootcare.co.uk/pomonafruits/find/apple-tree-gala-apl026?path=&ref=mall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `text-transform` is seriously under-defined in CSS specifications. Its [CSS 2.1 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-transform) does not even specify what “word” means. In computer contexts, “word” as a unit of text means just a maximal sequence of non-whitespace characters, so in your case, the string 'gala' with the apostrophes included would be one word, and its first character is the apostrophe. So it could be argued that IE is most right here, but other browsers have adopted other interpretations.

The [CSS3 Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-transform0) draft proposes to change or clarify the meaning so that the first *letter* (which would really mean “letter or digit”!) would be affected. So this would make the g in 'gaia' capitalized. But it still does not define “word”, e.g. whether “cutting-edge” is two words or one, or how many words there are in “rock’n’roll”.

The conclusion is that almost any method for capitalizing words is more reliable than the CSS way. If possible, modify the software that generates the pages so that it performs the desired operation server-side, according to the rules you prefer. Even using JavaScript is safer than CSS here.

Answer (score 0):

well the capitalize transform works differently on some browsers, for example for some browsers java-script would return Java-Script, some others would just return Java-script.

also keep in mind capitalize doesnt work with the rest of the letters of a word, it only changes the first one, so if you have the word intERNET, it would return IntERNET, leaving the reast as it is.

so my wild guess, is that ie7 & ie8 are taking 'gala' as a word byt making the ' the first character, so they are trying to capitalize a ' returning the same ', im dont know if there is a hack to it, but that might be something to get you started, try using gala instead of 'gala' just to test, and then see if there is a way to ignore the ' while capitalizing.